# Passing the dynamic URL in routing

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass the dynamic URL for routing.

`<DropdownItem value={age} id="dropdown-menu-align-right" to="/admin/viewaccount?id="{age} tag={Link}>`

I am just trying to append the parameter age in **to** path but it showing me error,

What is the way to archive this.

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: The Error it is showing is ' Unexpected token, expected "..." (116:110)', I have used {...age} instead of {age} but its also an failure it returns empty.

Answer (score 2):

I think i found the answer,

```
<DropdownItem value={age} id="dropdown-menu-align-right" to={`/admin/viewaccount?id=${age}`} tag={Link}>
```

Thanks you